# How to run Spark SQL JDBC/ODBC server and pyspark at the same time?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a one node deployment of Spark. I am running JDBC/ODBC server on it. Which works fine. However, if at the same time I use pyspark to save a table (`df.write.saveAsTable()`) I get a very long error message. I think the core part to it is this:

```
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /root/spark/bin/metastore_db.
```

Doing some research, I've found that this is caused by Spark creating a new session which tries to create another instance of Derby which causes an error. The solution offered is to shut down all other spark-shell processes. However if I do that then ODBC server stops running.

What can I do to have both running at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use derby network server instead of the default embedded version so it can be shared by multiple processes. Or you use another datastore such as MySQL.

After installing derby network server, you can copy the derby-client.jar file into the spark jars directory and then edit the file `conf/hive-site.xml` with something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
      <value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true</value>
      <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
      <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</value>
      <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think here lies my confusion about Spark SQL (I am really new to Spark).  I don't understand completely what role does derby or a network database plays in Spark system. If I run embedded version then it points to the data on the server. This make sense. What happens if I have MySQL? Does it point to the data files on the Spark server? Does it copy it over?

Comment: Database schema meta information (table structure definition and reference to data that you create with "CREATE TABLE" for example) are stored in a metastore (by default embedded Derby running in the JVM that stores the files in the directory metastore_db). But in this mode, the data can only be accessed by one process at a time (they put a lock). You can also choose to store these metadata in another database (e.g., MySQL) or to use Derby network database that can be accessed by multiple processes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I am having trouble configuring this whole thing properly. I have installed derby network server, put derbyclient.jar into spark jars, added the xml file like you said. When I try to use spark sql I get connection refused error. Do I need to do anything else? Do I need to set up a database on the network derby server? Do I need to create a user for spark app??

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. The issue was you don't need to specify the port near localhost.